# Selecting Fields and Join Clause

Tags: sql, db2

I have two tables, **TableA:**

```
- Original_Location
- Units
```

and **TableB:**

```
- Original_Loc
- Adjacent_Loc
- Direction (up/down/left/right from original loc)
```

My goal is to return the original location, the adjacent location, the direction, and the number of units at the *adjacent loc*. So far, I've only been able to return the units from the original loc.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
Select Original_Location,
Units,
TableB.Adjacent_Loc,
TableB.Direction

From TableA

Inner Join

Select *
From TableB

On TableA.Original_Location = TableB.Original_Loc
```

My thought is that I might need to change the fields I'm selecting before the inner join, or potentially join on Original_Location = Adjacent_Loc.

Comment: Could you please provide the meaning of your table and columns, what was the purpose of this structure?

Comment: @mostafa8026 Think of a location as a spot on a shelf. I want to see how many units are in each of the surrounding spots on the shelf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Join syntax is not right. First you don't need to "select" anything from Table B, your initial SELECT is getting data from the joined tables (A and B) as if they were 1 table. Secondly, you need to specify which fields to join the tables with.

Your join will be something like :-

```
From TableA Inner Join TableB
on TableA.Original_Loc = TableB.Original_Loc
```

Once you have got your joins right, you need to make another join to TableA to get the Units. This time you are joining the Adjacent_Loc in Table B to the Original_Location in Table A - which will have the Units value you need.

My example below uses aliases to identify each table (there are now 2 references to TableA so they need to be identified separately). So when you do the second join to TableA, this has the alias of c to differentiate it from the first TableA reference. You then need to select the Units from c.

```
Select a.Original_Location, c.Units, b.Adjacent_Loc, b.Direction
From TableA a Inner Join TableB b On a.Original_Location = b.Original_Loc
inner join TableA c on b.Adjacent_Loc = c.Original_Location
```

Comment: This will still return the units from the original location, correct? I want the units at the adjacent location.